# Is Jesus the real name of Jesus or is it some kind of translation?

Tags: translation, name-of-jesus, hebrew

Do these small names we found in bible like Peter, Paul, Jesus, Christ used in Jerusalem or Israel 2000 years ago or are they just translations?

Since Jesus was not speaking English, what was his real name?

Is there any list of real names with English translations available from the original languages?

Can we actually translate a name? A simple change may be possible as the comment says Yeshua to Jesus. My actual question is if you look into the names in that area , they are much complex. Its not that simple names.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Israelis
So the name should be more complex in old days; is it?

Do you think somebody translated to simple names to be practical and realistic and popular? Please suggest any materials if available.

Comment: The name Jesus was transliterated into English from Iesus, which came from Yeshua.

Comment: "The name Jesus was transliterated into English from Iesus, which came from Yeshua." - More accurately, "'Jesus' is the English transliteration of the Greek name Ἰησοῦς, which is the Greek transliteration of the Hebrew name יֵשׁוּעַ."

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 don't forget the Latin :-)

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81  i think what you suggested is just writing the name in another language . but what we have to know how they call it. We should have Yeshua . why translation is needed , Like jesus in spanish, they call hesus  .Latin i don't see any change . google translate helped  :-)

Comment: You can "know how they call it" by using IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) phonemes. Yeshua, Jesus, Hesus, etc. are not translations. They are transliterations, but even then, they don't really give an accurate pronunciation of the original name(s).

Comment: I'm understanding this question to be, "Are biblical names translated or not, and what is the real name of Jesus?"  To me, this is not too broad.  But if the question is actually asking for the "real names" of all the people in the Bible, as it could be read, I will vote to close.

Comment: If that question doesn't do it, then see these other questions about the name of Jesus specifically: [1](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/12319) [2](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4581) [3](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/31748) [4](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/7062). If none of these questions I've linked answer the question, I think it's because you're looking for a huge list, as this part indicates: `Is there any list of real names with English translations available from the original languages?` Also, I find the bit about "complexity" unclear.

Comment: @Flimzy I don't think it is a duplicate. One can probably get the same or similar answer from the other, but the question and its intentions are different.

Comment: @AChildofGod: 1) The definition of a duplicate question is that the answer addresses the question. 2) I would have indicated [this](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/45436/20) as the duplicate, but it was also closed as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: @Flimzy oh. I wasn't didn't know

Comment: @Zod I am undoing your edit because there is already an existing answer that would be invalidated by your edit.  (Also, there is nothing wrong with duplicate questions - they potentially help readers find what they are looking for.)  If you have a follow-up question, you should ask it as a new question.  However, "broadening" is not usually a good idea - Stack Exchange questions need to be narrowly focused to be answerable.  There is no universal answer to hold were the English names arrived at - different names have different histories.

Comment: Very Closely Related to: [What is the Origin of the Name of "Jesus"?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/52022/the-messiahs-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jesus is a translation of the Greek Ιησούς. It is the Greek version of the Hebrew ישוע (Yeshua). ישוע (Yeshua) comes from the Hebrew יהושע which is transliterated Yehoshu. This is translated as Joshua. Jesus spoke Hebrew at that time, as well as most Jews. Peter is a translation of Πέτρος (Pétros). This is a Greek version of the Hebrew כיפא (Keypha') which means "Rock".

[Main Source](http://www.city-data.com/forum/christianity/1791364-whats-name-apostles-aramaic.html)

Comment: I did a google search and found that. This answer is more of a mix of other sources as well. Mostly former knowledge. The site I sourced has more info.

Comment: `It is the Greek version of the Hebrew יהושע (Yeshua), which translates to Joshua.` This is a little bit confused.  יהושע (as in the OT book of Joshua) is transliterated *yehoshua*.  [Aramaic later made](https://archive.org/stream/dictionaryoftarg01jastuoft#page/600/mode/1up) ישוע (*yeshua*). Greek only has /y/ as vowel /i/, doesn’t have /sh/, and likes to end names with /s/ --->   Ιησούς = *Iesous*.

Comment: @Susan Yeshua is a shorter version of Yehoshua.

Comment: Clearly. It still doesn’t make any sense to write *yeshua* as  if it’s a transliteration of יהושע, and to my knowledge you can’t get to the former without Aramaic.

Comment: Okay I am about to add that information

Comment: @Susan - Yeshua is actually in the Hebrew texts as well.  It is also translated into iesos in the greek as well.